# Telerik HtmlChart Multiple LineSeries

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, telerik

2 issues, I'm trying to create a chart that has a simple Y axis and an X axis. Y Axis is 'Units' X axis a date range (1 week), here is my SQL Query:

```
SELECT     dbo.ProductSales.OrderDate, dbo.ProductSales.ProductID, dbo.ProductSales.UnitsSold, dbo.Product.Name
                                FROM         dbo.ProductSales INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Product ON dbo.ProductSales.ProductID = dbo.Product.ProductID

                                WHERE     (DistributionCentreID = 3)
                                GROUP BY dbo.ProductSales.OrderDate, dbo.ProductSales.ProductID, dbo.ProductSales.UnitsSold, dbo.Product.Name
                                HAVING      (OrderDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/10/2013', 103)) AND (OrderDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '07/10/2013', 103))
```

This produces this kind of data:

OrderDate             ProductID      UnitsSold             Name 
2013-10-01    10                        46                               Product Name

2013-10-01    11                        29                               Product Other Name

...etc

This needs to be grouped by week to week, so if a user selects a 30 day period it would group into the relevent weeks. This is the first issue.

Second issue is getting this data itno a chart. I'm using Telerik RadControls and the HtmlChart control specifically.

I have had a go of this but I'm unable to figure out how to set the X (date) value, which might be easier once I've figured out how to group into weeks.

Example code:

```
var htmlChart = new RadHtmlChart
                        {
                            ID = "htmlChart",
                            Width = Unit.Pixel(680),
                            Height = Unit.Pixel(400)
                        };

    htmlChart.Legend.Appearance.Position = ChartLegendPosition.Bottom;

    htmlChart.PlotArea.XAxis.TitleAppearance.Text = "Date";
    htmlChart.PlotArea.YAxis.TitleAppearance.Text = "Units Sold";

    htmlChart.PlotArea.XAxis.MajorTickType = TickType.Outside;

    htmlChart.PlotArea.XAxis.MinorTickType = TickType.Outside;

    List<productSalesTrend.productsalesTrendbyDates> data = trendAnalysisbyDate(1);

    foreach (string product in data.GroupBy(x => x.productName).Select(x => x.Key))
    {
        IEnumerable<productSalesTrend.productsalesTrendbyDates> productData = data.Where(x => product != null && x.productName == product);

        foreach (var productsalesTrendData in productData)
        {

            LineSeries areaSeries = htmlChart.PlotArea.Series[0] as LineSeries;




        }

    }

    HtmlChartHolder.Controls.Add(htmlChart);
```

If you need any more info, just ask.

Thanks for your time and i look forward to any replies/help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to show date values in RadHtmlChart:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/examples/functionality/dateaxis/defaultcs.aspx

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart-date-axis.html

This will show you how you can use data navigation to preselect a given week and let users browse through all data:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/examples/functionality/datanavigation/defaultcs.aspx

To create series and their items programmatically, examine their API:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart-server-side-api-configure-series.html

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart-server-side-api-configure-series-items.html
SeriesItems have constructors that can take as arguments the y-value.

If you only want one week, tweak the sql query to return the relevant data only (you seem to have that already, you may consider using parameters to get the dates from code): 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.ASPX